# Ionic v6 transparent body (@capacitor/google-maps)

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic6

In the docs you can read *"...as the developer, you must ensure that the webview is transparent all the way through the layers to the very bottom"*. I've googled about that but found no solution. In my case it works if I set the  as transparent but the only way I could find to do this is changing --ion-background-color: transparent; in variables.css but this affects a lot of other elements which need a new CSS to correct the background.

Is there a way to change only the body to transparent?

Before someone asks, I already tried with:

```
ion-content { --background: none; }
ion-content { --background: transparent; }
:root { --background: transparent; }
document.getElementsByTag('body') /*and then changing the style but in Android doesn't work*/
```

And some other which probably I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
ion-content {
  --background: transparent;
}

body {
  background: transparent;
}
```